# UIViews side by side in a horizontal scroll view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm currently trying to learn the `UIScrollView`. As an exercise, I simply want `UIView`s with labels that show texts, and I want those views to be within that `UIScrollView`. To do this, I have two `mutableArray`s; one will contain the texts, and the other will contain the `UIView`s. Below are the methods that initialize these arrays.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)postViewsArray
{
    if (_postViewsArray == nil) _postViewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _postViewsArray;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)postsArray
{
    if (_postsArray == nil) _postsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _postsArray;
}
```

Next, I fill up those two arrays with values. For the `postsArray` I only placed static texts. But for the `postViewsArray` I used `NSNull` as a placeholder. This is for optimization purposes, especially memory management, when I already need to load views with images in the future. So below were the methods to set those arrays up.

```
- (void) setupPostsArray {
    [self.postsArray addObject:@"Hello"];
    [self.postsArray addObject:@"You are doing good"];
    [self.postsArray addObject:@"By this exercise"];
    [self.postsArray addObject:@"In scroll views, paging enabled :)"]; 
}

- (void) setupPostViewsArray {
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.postsArray count]; i++) {
        [self.postViewsArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
    } 
}
```

There, simple. Now let's get to the more challenging part. So here in `loadMyPages` method, first off I initialize my `scrollView`, set it's `contentSize`, and add it as a subview of my top - level view, which is `self.view`. Here, I also do iteration in creating the "pages" that I can swipe through, it's content, background color. There it is.

However, when I run the app, I can only see one `view` that can be swiped. And it seemed that 3 more `views` can fit inside this scroll view. I did `NSLog`s to check the `page`s being created and it's `subviews` and it seemed to work fine as I see the logs in the debug area. Note that the `view` that I can see has the last value of my `postArray`. A friend suspects that the other `view`s were overlapped instead of being viewed side by side.

Shed some light for me here kind ones :) Below is my `loadMyPages` method and perhaps take a look on this if you guys are up for the challenge.

```
- (void) loadMyPages
    {
        NSLog(@"loads view");
        CGRect pagingScrollViewFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        self.pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:pagingScrollViewFrame];

        self.pagingScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagingScrollViewFrame.size.width * [self.postsArray count], pagingScrollViewFrame.size.height);


        [self.view addSubview:self.pagingScrollView];

        // iteration to enumerate creating of UIViews
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.postsArray count]; i++) {

            NSLog(@"Creating views?");

            UIView *pageView = [self.postViewsArray objectAtIndex:i];

                if ((NSNull *) pageView == [NSNull null]) {


                    // create a new UIView
                    UIView *page = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

                    page.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

                    // set text label
                    self.postLabel.text = [self.postsArray objectAtIndex:i];

                    // add the label to the created UIView
                    [page addSubview:self.postLabel];

                    // then lastly, add each element of the postViewsArray as a subview of the pagingScrollView
                    [self.postViewsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:page];

                    [self.pagingScrollView addSubview:[self.postViewsArray objectAtIndex:i]];

                    NSLog(@"this view %@ has this post value: %@", page, [page subviews]);
                    NSLog(@"subviews of scrollview: %@", [self.pagingScrollView subviews]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, you want to layout views horizontally, like a deck of cards placed side by side, and then scroll from one to another, just like iOS default photos app.

To do this, each view must have an x origin difference value equal to the width of your view's frame or scrollView frame. However your current code

```
[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]
```

Sets the same origin for each view, resulting in overlapping. Change your code to following

```
[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(i*320), 0, yourWidth, yourHeight];
```

The `i` factor will increase the x value placing each subsequent view right next to the previous view.

Note: Adjust 320 and 0 as x, y values to suit your needs

Comment: Thanks for the urgent response! You've got what I want to do. I'll try this one out.

Comment: I did this `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 320, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)]` and it seemed to be Ok now with regards the `View`s. However, I found another problem, only the last value of my `postArray` is being shown at the last `view`. Still the first three `postArray` values were not shown in the first three `view`s.

Comment: simply because you are adding the same self.postLabel field to all views and also changing its value from postsArray. Each iteration overwrites the previous value of self.postLabel thus leaving the last value in the field. create multiple postLabels for each view. also, accept the answer if it solved your problem. =)

Comment: Thanks, one last thing that's a bit blurry is the creation of multiple labels. Do you mean I should drag out 3 more labels from object library? Or is there some kind of `reuseIdentifier` for a label?

Comment: you want to set label on each view right? if so, create the label programmatically inside the loop where you create the UIViews.

Answer (score 1):

The frame you are providing to each view is not proper so your views are overlapping:
 UIView *page = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

because each view is getting same frame.

Instead of this you should provide frame as follows:

```
UIView *page1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

UIView *page2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(page1.frame.origin.x+page1.frame.size.width, 0, page1.frame.size.width, page1.frame.size.height)];
```

and so on.

Hope you got what I want to convey.

Before For loop create some CGRect variable.

```
CGRect theViewFrame = CGRectZero;
```

Inside for loop provide page frame and initialize theViewFrame as follows:

```
page.frame = CGRectMake(theViewFrame.origin.x+self.view.bounds.size.width, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    theViewFrame = pageView.frame;
```

So when every time the loop is iterated the theViewFrame will contain latest view frame.

Comment: I've got what you mean. With that, I've got this idea of setting the origin of the next `view` to be the upper right corner of the previous `view`. Can you help me out how to translate that in code?

Comment: Do you mean `theViewFrame = page.frame`? Tried this one but the first `view` created is not shown first. I have to swipe right to see the created view.